# Como obter os elementos em comum entre arrays?

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho um array que recebo dos checkboxes que o usuário escolhe

```
const check_frutas = ["banana", "uva", "pera"];
```

E no meu código, preciso comparar esse array com outros para obter o mais similar.

```
const frutas_a = ["banana", "limao", "pera", "goiaba"];
const frutas_b = ["tomate", "tangerina", "pera", "melancia"];
```

Como faço essa comparação pra obter um resultado do tipo "O array mais similar é frutas_b"?

Answer (score 3):

Faça a intersecção entre o conjunto de entrada e os outros conjuntos e cheque a quantidade de itens resultante desta operação.

Abaixo tem um exemplo de implementação.

Note que essa implementação não leva em consideração questões de performance (provavelmente você nem vai querer se importar com isso trabalhando com arrays tão pequenos). Portanto, a solução tem um tempo de execução O(n²) — um loop no `filter` e um no `includes`.

```js
const check_frutas = ["banana", "uva", "pera"]
const frutas_a = ["banana", "limao", "pera", "goiaba"]
const frutas_b = ["tomate", "tangerina", "pera", "melancia"]
const frutas_c = ["pera", "melancia", "uva", "banana"]

let best_match = []
for(arr of [frutas_a, frutas_b, frutas_c])
{
  let interseccao = check_frutas.filter(x => arr.includes(x))
  console.log(interseccao)
  if(best_match.length < interseccao.length)
    best_match = interseccao  
}

console.log(best_match)
```

Answer (score 1):

Experimente utilizar um loop e incrementar de acordo com acertos. Como assim? Vamos criar tipo um sistema de "pontuação" e o array com mais "pontos" é o mais parecido.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Array com o checkbox do usuário
  const check_frutas = ["banana", "uva", "pera"];
  // Arrays pra comparação
  const frutas_a = ["banana", "limao", "pera", "goiaba"];
  const frutas_b = ["tomate", "tangerina", "pera", "melancia"];
  // Reconhece o botão
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

  // Função pra fazer a comparação entre dois arrays
  function compararArrays(arrayAComparar, arrayASerComparado) {
    // Variáveis pra contar os "pontos" dos arrays
    var pontos = 0;
    // Loop para verificação
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayASerComparado.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < arrayAComparar.length; j++) {
        if (arrayASerComparado[i] === arrayAComparar[j]) {
          pontos += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    return pontos;
  }

  // Aqui vou escrever na tela qual é mais parecido quando o usuário clicar no botão
  btn.onclick = function() {
    var pontos1 = compararArrays(frutas_a, check_frutas);
    var pontos2 = compararArrays(frutas_b, check_frutas);
    var resultado;
    // Compara qual é mais parecido
    if (pontos1 > pontos2) {
      resultado = "O array é mais parecido com o array A";
    } else if (pontos1 < pontos2) {
      resultado = "O array é mais parecido com o array B";
    } else {
      resultado = "O array é tão parecido com o array A quanto com o array B";
    }

    // Escreve na tela qual array é mais parecido
    alert(resultado);
  };
};
```

```html
<button id="btn">Comparar Arrays</button>
```

OBS: Utilizei pra comparar eles um método conhecido como [Bubble Sort](https://www.embarcados.com.br/algoritmos-de-ordenacao-bubble-sort/)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow, o método abaixo verifica a similaridade e retorna o elemento que ele considera mais similar!

```
function checkSimilar(collection, a, b) {
    var first=0, last=0;

    for (var i in collection) {    

        if (a.indexOf(collection[i]) !== -1) {
            first++;  
        }  
        if (b.indexOf(collection[i]) !== -1) { 
            last++;    
        }
    }   
    if (first == last) {
       //iguais
       return {all:[a, b], first:null, last:null};   
    } else if (first > last) {    
       //a é mais similar
       return {all:null, first:a, last:null};  
    } else {
       //b é mais similar
       return {all:null, first:null, last:b};
    }
} 

var similar = checkSimilar(["banana", "uva", "pera"], ["banana", "limao", "pera", "goiaba"],["tomate", "tangerina", "pera", "melancia"]);

console.log(similar)
```

Outra opção de retorno, seria editar o código conforme sua preferência:

```
 if (first == last) {
    //iguais
    return [a, b];   
 } else if (first > last) {    
    //a é mais similar
    return a;  
 } else {
    //b é mais similar
    return b;
 }
```

ou:

```
 if (first == last) {
     //iguais
     return  'a e b são semelhantes';   
 } else if (first > last) {    
     //a é mais similar
     return 'a é mais similar';  
 } else {
     //b é mais similar
     return 'b é mais similar';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz esse algoritmo simples que retorna o array que contém o conteúdo mais similar. (**Provavelmente existe uma implementação mais performática**).

```
function similarities(arrayCheck, arrayOne, arrayTwo){

    let arrayOneCount = 0;
    let arrayTwoCount = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < arrayCheck.length; i++){

        if(arrayOne.includes(arrayCheck[0])) arrayOneCount++;
        if(arrayTwo.includes(arrayCheck[0])) arrayTwoCount++;
    }

    if(arrayOneCount > arrayTwoCount)
        return arrayOne;

    if(arrayOneCount < arrayTwoCount)
        return arrayTwo;

    return arrayOne;
}
```

Recomendo efetuar uma pesquisa mais aprofundada antes de efetuar a pergunta. Já existia uma pergunta similar a sua [aqui no próprio stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948761/count-similarities-between-two-arrays-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Segue outra forma:

```
const check_frutas = ["banana", "uva", "pera"];
const frutas_a = ["banana", "limao", "pera", "goiaba"];
const frutas_b = ["tomate", "tangerina", "pera", "melancia"];
const frutas_c = ["pera", "melancia", "uva", "banana"];
const lista = [frutas_a, frutas_b, frutas_c];

const retorno = lista.map((x) => x.filter((y) => check_frutas.includes(y)))
                        .reduce((acc,cur,idx) => { cur.length > acc.matchCout && (acc = { matchCout: cur.length, array: lista[idx] }); return acc; }, { matchCout: 0, array: [] });
```

retorna:

```
{
array: ["pera", "melancia", "uva", "banana"],
matchCout: 3
}
```