# Comparar arrays ou strings e retornar uma array com todos elementos repetidos (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou usando uma função que retorna uma array multidimensional em que cada índice contem uma array de fatoração de números primos.
Essa função, por sua vez, pode aceitar uma quantidade variável de argumentos e retorna o mdc de quantos números forem passados como argumentos.

Ex: `mdc(60,100,150)` retorna uma array `mdcOperands = [ [2,2,3,5], [2,2,5,5], [2,3,5,5]];`

Eu quero comparar as distintas arrays dentro de `mdcOperands` pra retornar uma nova array com os `mdcOperands[i][j]` que se repetem em todas. Eu tentei fazer uma comparação vis a vis usando um nested for loop mas ele compara apenas `mdcOperands[i][j]` com `mdcOperands[i+1][j]`, mas há casos em que essa comparação não retorna um elemento, mas pode ser que o `mdcOperands[i][j]` se repita em `mdcOperands[i+1][j+2]` por exemplo, como em `mdcOperands[0][3]`, `mdcOperands[1][2]` e `mdcOperands [2][2]`.

Queria saber se existe um jeito fácil de comparar essas arrays de números fatorados com `i` variável ou se eu poderia transformar os resultados em strings e comparar a repetição simultaneamente em todas strings, talvez usando um regEx que aceite uma variável como valor de match, por ex:

```
'2235'
'2255'
'2355'
```

e retornar '25', que eu poderia transformar em um array `[2,5]` e retornar a função `mdc(60,100,150) = 2 * 5 = 10 (mdc dos três numeros)`. Lembrando que a função `mdc()` que eu defini aceita argumentos de 1 até o máximo possível.

**Edit: Trecho de código upado dos comentários.**

```
function compareFactors(mdcOperands) {
  let comparingFactors = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
  let mdcFactors = [];
  for (let mdcOperandsIndex = 0; mdcOperandsIndex < mdcOperands.length - 1; mdcOperandsIndex++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < mdcOperands[mdcOperandsIndex].length; j++) {
      if (mdcOperands[mdcOperandsIndex][j] === mdcOperands[mdcOperandsIndex + 1][j]) {
        mdcFactors.push(mdcOperands[mdcOperandsIndex][j])
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: o que você tentou fazer para resolver? Posta o seu codigo para podermos ajudar

Comment: function compareFactors(mdcOperands) {
            //let comparingFactors = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
            let mdcFactors = [];

            for (let mdcOperandsIndex = 0; mdcOperandsIndex < mdcOperands.length -1; mdcOperandsIndex++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < mdcOperands[mdcOperandsIndex].length; j++) {
                    if (mdcOperands[mdcOperandsIndex][j] === mdcOperands[mdcOperandsIndex+1][j]) {
                        mdcFactors.push(mdcOperands[mdcOperandsIndex][j])
                    }
                }
               
            }
        }

Comment: foi mal, to começando a aprender programação faz pouco tempo e não sei usar o stackoverflow, acabei vindo parar aqui porque não achei nada em lugar nenhum, pelo menos não com conceitos que eu saiba usar pra pesquisar. O mais próximo que achei disso seria transformar em strings e usar o RegEx (que não faço ideia de como opera) e fazer algum tipo de match entre 2 strings ENQUANTO variaveis, tpo str1.match(str2) mas sempre retorna null (tentei no console do browser).

Comment: Vá direto ao assunto não precisa explicar que é iniciante. Formate o texto da pergunta com markdown. Veja [ask], [help], [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas), [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade) e faça o nosso [tour].

Comment: obrigado @AugustoVasques

Comment: Acho que você está complicando uma coisa simples. Veja [esse exemplo de função](https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/MDC#index.js) do calculo do mdc entre n números.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está complicando desnecessariamente as coisas. Se quer calcular o MDC, não precisa fatorar os números, existe um algoritmo bem simples para tal:

```js
// calcula o MDC entre dois números
function mdc2(a, b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        var r = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Claro, existem também versões recursivas, já que a definição matemática é assim (`MDC(a, b)`: se `b` for zero, `a` é a resposta, senão o resultado é o `MDC(b, a % b)`), mas eu não usaria recursão quando o algoritmo iterativo acima é bem mais simples (e também [mais rápido](https://jsbench.me/wmks7fnrmg/1)).

Depois, para generalizar para vários números, basta saber que `MDC(a, b, c)` é igual a `MDC(MDC(a, b), c)`. Ou seja, basta calcular o MDC de dois em dois números. Ficaria assim:

```js
// calcula o MDC entre dois números
function mdc2(a, b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        var r = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = r;
    }
    return a;
}

function mdc(...numeros) { // calcula o MDC entre vários números
    if (numeros.length === 0) // não tem nenhum número
        return 0;
    if (numeros.length === 1) // só tem um número, ele próprio é o MDC
        return numeros[0];

    // calcula o MDC entre os dois primeiros números
    var result = mdc2(numeros[0], numeros[1]);
    // calcula o MDC deste com os restantes
    for (var i = 2; i < numeros.length; i++) {
        result = mdc2(result, numeros[i]);
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(mdc(60, 100, 150)); // 10
```

---

Esta é a forma mais simples de resolver o problema principal (encontrar o MDC entre vários números).

Mas só para constar, se fosse para encontrar os elementos em comum entre vários arrays, daria para fazer como a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/522700/112052), ou como [alguma das opções desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/368441/112052), ou ainda com `Set` (que acredito ser menos pior, pois um `Set` já é [otimizado para não permitir elementos repetidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510118/112052) e por isso é [mais rápido do que ficar processando os arrays diretamente](https://jsbench.me/etks7gaqyk/1)):

```js
// calcula a intersecção entre dois sets
function intersect(s1, s2) {
    var result = new Set();
    for (var x of s1)
        if (s2.has(x))
            result.add(x);
    return result;
}

// calcula a intersecção entre todos os arrays
let mdcOperands = [[2, 2, 3, 5], [2, 2, 5, 5], [2, 3, 5, 5]];
let result = new Set(mdcOperands[0]);
for(var i = 1; i < mdcOperands.length; i++) {
    result = intersect(result, new Set(mdcOperands[i]));
}

// multiplica os elementos da intersecção
let mdc = 1;
for (var n of result) {
    mdc *= n;
}
console.log(mdc); // 10
```

Mas se a ideia é só calcular o MDC entre vários números (e não necessariamente "obter elementos em comum entre vários arrays"), a primeira solução é a mais indicada (por não precisar criar vários arrays e nem calcular a intersecção entre eles).

---

Quanto a concatenar os números e usar regex, esqueça, não faz sentido. Por exemplo, se um dos arrays tiver `[7, 19]` e outro tiver `[719]`, em ambos os casos, ao juntar os dígitos você terá `719`. Como você vai diferenciar? É mais simples manipular os números usando os próprios arrays (ou convertendo-os para `Set`, como feito acima).

Comment: Caramba,  eu compliquei demais mesmo. Realmente não tinha pensado nessa questão do RegEx, na verdade ainda não consigo usar o RegEx e realmente não fazia sentido mesmo.  Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: não sabia disso, vou aceitá-la sim :)

Answer (score 0):

Numa solução geral, para encontrar os itens repetidos, você pode transformar esse array multidimensional em um único array, já que nesse caso (para achar os repetidos) as dimensões não importam.

```
let mdcOperands = [ [2,2,3,5], [2,2,5,5], [2,3,5,5]];
let flatOperands = mdcOperands.flat()
let repetidos = []
flatOperands.map(function(item,index){
  if((flatOperands.indexOf(item) !== index) && (repetidos.indexOf(item)=== -1)){
      repetidos.push(item)}
})
```

Aqui usamos o método **flat**, para fazer um array único, com todos elementos dos sub arrays, depois filtramos com o método **map** e usando o **if**, os itens que estão repetidos.

O que o **if** está fazendo é verificar se o item atual tem a mesma posição atual, se isso for verdade, significa que é a primeira aparição dele no array, até então ele é único, caso contrário, significa que já existe um item igual no array, então ele é repetido.

A segunda verificação é se esse item, já está no array dos repetidos (se o **indexOf** retornar -1, não está), caso não estiver, o item é adicionado à lista de repetidos.

Isso é uma solução geral, mas como você quer restringir a repetição entre em todos os arrays **ao mesmo tempo**, podemos fazer uma espécie de nested loops.

```
for (let i = 0;i<repetidos.length;i++){
  
  mdcOperands.map((item,index)=>{
    item.indexOf(repetidos[i]) === -1 ? repetidos.splice(i,1):''
  })
}
```

Aqui com o `for`, pegamos cada item repetido e depois submetemos ele a um teste no `map` do mdcOperands. Ele passará por cada sub lista e uma verificação vai ser feita, se ele não estiver na sublista atual, significa que ele não serve para nós, já que queremos que esteja **em todas as sublistas ao mesmo tempo**, se em ao menos uma ele não está, podemos excluí-lo, com o `splice`, que está removendo o item, da posição atual. Caso ele passe no teste , nada acontece. Assim, só restará no array, os itens que passarem por cada teste, em todas as sublistas. E enfim, temos o retorno:

```
console.log(repetidos)//[2,5]
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Rubens!